# How to Avoid rarely used discrete feature values in a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, feature-engineering

On [Google's ML crash course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/representation/qualities-of-good-features) it states:

> Good feature values should appear more than 5 or so times in a data
>   set. Doing so enables a model to learn how this feature value relates
>   to the label. That is, having many examples with the same discrete
>   value gives the model a chance to see the feature in different
>   settings, and in turn, determine when it's a good predictor for the
>   label.

This make sense, but if that happens what should we do? For example, consider a dataset with `street_name` as feature and out 2000 rows, only 4 of them have `street_name` equal to "Learning St.".

Should we remove those rows containing rare feature values? Or what?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with Categorical Features can raise a few challenges. For instance, you might encounter features with high cardinality in certain values or the other case (your case), features with rare categories.

The first thing you can consider is, what you will lose if you drop those rows. What extra info do you get with keeping the rare categories. Here you probably need the domain knowledge of the project to identify the impact of the specific data. If your dataset is small or you don't feel safe to remove those rows, then you should look for alternatives.

The second approach is to group all the rare categories in one new called "Rare" or "Other". So, whenever you have a record with that value, you replace it with the new one.

Finally, you can try either a Dimentionality Reduction such as PCA or a Feature Hashing where you will map multiple categories in one new value.

Comment: But isn't PCA for the whole training data rather than a single feature data?

Comment: You can transform your categorical column with one-hot encoding and then perform PCA on those columns only. As for the second, just replace all the categories with lower than a limit cardinality with a new value such as "other".

Comment: Thank you. I guess I need into consideration all four approaches. My other question is that how do you implement your second approach? Do you add a boolean feature vector say, rare of length equal to number of feature and whenever an example, if for any feature has low cardinality for any value, we put 1, say (0,1,1,0,0) meaning there are rare values for 2nd an 3rd features.